# What are the anchor's "name" attributes on history's first website?

Tags: html, history

[History's first webpage](http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html) is still online and functional.

I was looking at its source out of interest and noticed that anchors consistently have a `name` attribute containing a stringified number, for example:

```html
<p>
  Everything there is online about W3 is linked directly or indirectly to this document,
  including an <a name="24" href="Summary.html">executive summary</a> of the project
  <!-- ... -->
</p>
```

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#name) that it used to be a sort of `id` attribute that targeted a specific location on the page, but this doesn't seem right in this case, since anchors also have `href`s.

[image: Screenshot of history's first webpage]

Does anyone know what this was for?

Comment: I hope the downvotes are not because this is off topic? I [tried to make sure it wasn't](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5633/is-programming-history-on-topic) before posting, but if I was wrong, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a marker for a URL fragment. You can see the link for viola has the url

http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/Status.html#35

When you follow the link the tag with the name attribute set to the fragment is selected/scrolled to

Comment: Thanks, what confused me is that other links (like the one for NeXTStep) have a `name` but no `#` in their href, and in that case the `name` doesn't seem to be doing anything (try clicking NeXTStep). The one for Viola only works because it has the `#35` at the end of the href

Comment: yes, it so _other_ pages can link to the tag _if_ they want to. so you give every section a name in case someone else wants to link to it

Answer (score 3):

The `name` attribute in older versions of HTML is exactly equivalent to the `id` attribute in later versions of HTML. There is no difference between the two, except for the fact that in modern HTML every element can have an `id` but in older HTML only some elements could have a `name`.

Comment: In addition to this answer. [RFC1866 7.4 : Fragment Identifiers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1866#section-7.4) . This RFC belongs to [HTML 2.0 publicated  November 1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#HTML_2)